# UICollectionView supplementary view issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I've encountered the following issue while dealing with a UICollectionView. The last header supplementary view is populated first in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:. Here's an example of that issue

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell section %li",(long)indexPath.section);
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"header section %li",(long)indexPath.section);
    NSLog(@"%@",kind);
    static NSString *headerIdentifier = @"MyHeader";
    CollectionViewHeader *header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:headerIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return header;
}
```

For a particular dataSource model this produces the following output in the console

```
2014-04-02 12:30:50.195 fdasfsad[6353:60b] cell section 0
2014-04-02 12:30:50.200 fdasfsad[6353:60b] cell section 1
2014-04-02 12:30:50.203 fdasfsad[6353:60b] cell section 2
2014-04-02 12:30:50.205 fdasfsad[6353:60b] cell section 3
2014-04-02 12:30:50.207 fdasfsad[6353:60b] cell section 4
2014-04-02 12:30:50.209 fdasfsad[6353:60b] header 0
2014-04-02 12:30:50.210 fdasfsad[6353:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:30:50.212 fdasfsad[6353:60b] header 2
2014-04-02 12:30:50.214 fdasfsad[6353:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:30:50.216 fdasfsad[6353:60b] header 4
2014-04-02 12:30:50.218 fdasfsad[6353:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:30:50.219 fdasfsad[6353:60b] header 1
2014-04-02 12:30:50.221 fdasfsad[6353:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:30:50.223 fdasfsad[6353:60b] header 3
2014-04-02 12:30:50.224 fdasfsad[6353:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
```

Is this right? In the case of the supplementary view the last section is always populated first?

**UPDATE: POSSIBLE BUG DISCOVERED**

Up to now I was testing the app on an iPad Mini. The project is setup as an iPhone project. When I test the app on the iPhone simulator I'm getting the expected result:

```
2014-04-02 12:35:35.251 fdasfsad[3276:60b] cell section 0
2014-04-02 12:35:35.253 fdasfsad[3276:60b] cell section 1
2014-04-02 12:35:35.254 fdasfsad[3276:60b] cell section 2
2014-04-02 12:35:35.254 fdasfsad[3276:60b] cell section 3
2014-04-02 12:35:35.255 fdasfsad[3276:60b] cell section 4
2014-04-02 12:35:35.255 fdasfsad[3276:60b] cell section 5
2014-04-02 12:35:35.256 fdasfsad[3276:60b] header 0
2014-04-02 12:35:35.256 fdasfsad[3276:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:35:35.256 fdasfsad[3276:60b] header 1
2014-04-02 12:35:35.257 fdasfsad[3276:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:35:35.257 fdasfsad[3276:60b] header 2
2014-04-02 12:35:35.257 fdasfsad[3276:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:35:35.258 fdasfsad[3276:60b] header 3
2014-04-02 12:35:35.258 fdasfsad[3276:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:35:35.259 fdasfsad[3276:60b] header 4
2014-04-02 12:35:35.259 fdasfsad[3276:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
2014-04-02 12:35:35.259 fdasfsad[3276:60b] header 5
2014-04-02 12:35:35.260 fdasfsad[3276:60b] UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
```

Could this be a bug in Xcode 5?

Comment: Are you sure that `kind` will be always equal to `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`? Can you share output when you logged the `kind` string in the method?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I've edited the code above. It seems I'm only getting UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader in both circumstances. Note that on the story board I've got a UICollectionViewController which is hooked up to the associated class. It's also the rootViewController. It only has a UICollectionViewCell prototype and a UICollectionReusableView Prototype both of which have the associated identifiers set as in the code above.

Comment: I never met such a condition. I tried it for you just now and the result is normal. Are you able to try your collection view with more sections (say 10) and share your results?

Comment: Changed it to 10 sections. Now the log is even weirder (0,2,4,1,3). Though I've made some progress. The initial result comes from debugging on an iPad Mini. When I test it on the iPhone simulator Im getting the correct order (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4).

Comment: Like I've added to the post above on the iPhone simulator everything shows up fine. However testing on an iPad Mini or the iPad simulator produces the unexpected results mentioned. Could you verify this? I think this might be a bug in Xcode or iOS.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any further info about behaviour. Maybe you should report this as a bug.